# Mongodb to s3 storage not working

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, aws, linux

I want to export mongodb to s3 bucket in ubuntu 14.04.

**`mongo_to_s3.sh`**

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST=localhost

# DB name
DBNAME=<db_name>

# S3 bucket name
BUCKET=<s3_bucket_name>

# Linux user account
USER=ubuntu

# Current time
TIME=`/bin/date +%d-%m-%Y-%T`

# Backup directory
DEST=/home/$USER/tmp

# Tar file of backup directory
TAR=$DEST/../$TIME.tar

# Create backup dir (-p to avoid warning if already exists)
/bin/mkdir -p $DEST

# Log
echo "Backing up $HOST/$DBNAME to s3://$BUCKET/ on $TIME";

# Dump from mongodb host into backup directory
/usr/bin/mongodump -h $HOST -d $DBNAME -o $DEST

# Create tar of backup directory
/bin/tar cvf $TAR -C $DEST .

# Upload tar to s3
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp $TAR s3://$BUCKET/

# Remove tar file locally
/bin/rm -f $TAR

# Remove backup directory
/bin/rm -rf $DEST

# All done
echo "Backup available at https://s3.amazonaws.com/$BUCKET/$TIME.tar"
```

Also i have installed **[awscli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli)** for adding aws s3 configuration details.But when i run above script i am getting an error like this,

```
A client error (InvalidRequest) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

**`~/.aws/config`**

```
aws_access_key_id = **********
aws_secret_access_key =********
region=us-east-2
s3_signature_version=v4
```

bucket name and region are correct in my configuration. What is the issue here .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It got working ,when i create a new bucket with region `us-east-2`